# How to programmatically check JMX MBean operations and attributes?

Tags: java, jmx, websphere-7, mbeans

Suppose we have a MBean that has the following attributes and operations.

Attributes:
name
size

Operations:
getName()
getSize()

Is there a way to programmatically check for the attributes and operations?  I've been working with the IBM WebSphere MBeans and their documentation isn't very good.

For example, if you go to [IBMs Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp) and navigate to Network Deployment -> Reference -> Programming interfaces -> Mbean interfaces -> ThreadPool.  They only have attributes listed and no operations.

Using the WebSphere wsadmin tool, I can actually check to see the operations and attributes.  I'd like to know if there's a way to do this with all MBeans.

```
wsadmin>print Help.attributes(object)
Attribute                       Type                            Access
name                            java.lang.String                RO
maximumSize                     int                             RW
minimumSize                     int                             RW
inactivityTimeout               long                            RW
growable                        boolean                         RW
stats                           javax.management.j2ee.statistics.Stats  RO

wsadmin>print Help.operations(object)
Operation
java.lang.String getName()
int getMaximumPoolSize()
void setMaximumPoolSize(int)
int getMinimumPoolSize()
void setMinimumPoolSize(int)
long getKeepAliveTime()
void setKeepAliveTime(long)
boolean isGrowAsNeeded()
void setGrowAsNeeded(boolean)
javax.management.j2ee.statistics.Stats getStats()
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all @MD6380?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to programmatically check JMX MBean operations and attributes?

I can't quite tell if you are talking about programmatically finding the MBeans from inside the current JVM or remotely from a client.  There are a number of JMX client libraries.  You might want to try my [SimpleJMX package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/).

With my code you can do something like:

```
JmxClient client = new JmxClient(hostName, port);
Set<ObjectName> objectNames = getBeanNames() 
for (ObjectName name : objectNames) {
    MBeanAttributeInfo[] attributes = getAttributesInfo(name);
    MBeanOperationInfo[] operations = getOperationsInfo(name);
}
```

If you are asking about the current JVM then you should be able to get bean information from the internal beans this way:

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
Set<ObjectName> objectNames = server.queryNames(null, null);
for (ObjectName name : objectNames) {
    MBeanInfo info = server.getMBeanInfo(name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with simple JMX for ActiveMQ. Can be useful for someone in future with just replacing activeMQ values:

```
String brokerName = "AMQBroker";
String username = "";
String password = "";
String hostname = "localhost";
int port = 1099;

Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();
if (username != null || password != null) {
    String[] credentials = new String[] { username, password };
    env.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);
}

JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

// here is example for Type=Broker, can be different like
// "org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=" + brokerName + ",Type=Connection,ConnectorName=openwire,Connection=*"
// "org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=" + brokerName + ",*,Type=NetworkBridge" or same for Queue, Topic, Subscription
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=" + brokerName + ",Type=Broker");
Set<ObjectName> queryNames = conn.queryNames(name, null);
// here is set with one element, but can be more depending on ObjectName query
for (ObjectName objectName : queryNames) {
    System.out.println(objectName.getCanonicalName());
    // use attribute you can be interested in
    System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(objectName, "Slave"));
}
```