# how to ensure JMS listener is up without using jconsole?

Tags: java, jms

I Created Java message listener, how to monitor or alert when listener is down.
I have tried with JConsole is there any other way I should use.

Answer (score 1):

If the message broker you are using ships with a web console, you can use that. Like these for rabbitmq and activemq:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html
http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ provides [Advisory Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html), which allows you to watch the system using regular JMS messages.

Also note that what is "visible" with JConsole can be accessed programmatically, using JMX. Have a look at [How to programmatically check JMX MBean operations and attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342630/how-to-programmatically-check-jmx-mbean-operations-and-attributes). JMX mbeans, attributes and operation can also been accesses through HTTP with [Jolokia](http://jolokia.org/).